# Need to refresh token/add tags Firecloud messaging

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have managed to get my push notifications working on my Xamarin.Forms project. I was able to add new tags when using Google Cloud messaging (which is now deprecated) and having upgraded to FCM I am now only able to set tags upon first registration to the FCM-server.

```
var hub = new NotificationHub(myHubName,listenConnectionString, this);
var regId = hub.Register(token, myTags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;
```

How do I call FCM to refresh my instance-token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was just to "call" hub.Register with my updated tags. Register will remove all earlier tags and replace them with the new ones. Also it needs to be done in an own thread like this:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
   var regId = hub.Register(token, myTags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;
});
```